# GoogleCredentials Import error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to test the code located [Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/api/load_data_from_csv.py), however everytime I run it, it gives me a

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
ImportError: cannot import name GoogleCredentials
```

I'm not sure what it could be.. I've tried downgrading my python-api-client to = 1.1 as people suggested, tried to upgrade to the newest version...but to no avail. I'm really not sure how to solve this.

Please help! :)

Comment: How did you install oauth2client ?

Comment: @ClémentSchreiner I used pip install --target=my_app oauth2client. I believe that is correct? First time using libraries and all with Python, so I hope it's right! haha

Comment: after doing an update, it gives another error:

from oauth2client.anyjson import simplejson
ImportError: No module named anyjson

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem, after hours of pain and anger... turns out that you need to use oauth2client version 1.5... so doing:

```
pip install --target=my_app oauth2client==1.5
```

did the trick! Google Docs can be confusing some times!